# handling commas inside double quotes + awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Here is my file

```
$ cat -v test2
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"
"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"
```

this command add a column to the end

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$8=q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{$8=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$8); $8= q $8/(1024*1024)q}1' test2 | cat -v
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description","Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan","0.131383"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16","0"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -","0"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan","46.5744"
"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,"0.139818",OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN","108.486"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2","18.9218"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4","0"
```

my problem is this line

```
"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,"0.139818",OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
```

It changes to this

`"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,"0.139818",OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"`

which has this `"0.139818"` in the wrong place. 
It does not turn out like the others. The issue seems to be the commas that are enclosed in the double quotes in this column: 
`"OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,"0.139818",OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006"`

**What is the best way, or is it possible, to achieve this?** this is what I want the line to look like, like the other lines.

`"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)","0.139818"`

Maybe I need to tidy the data, this line in particular before it gets to awk.

---

### EDIT1 Answers worked out

change the delimiter from , to ; and add the new column at the end

```
$ sed 's/","/";"/g' < test2 | awk -F';' -v OFS=';' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$8=q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $8= q n/(1024*1024)q}1'
"Rec Open Date";"MSISDN";"IMEI";"Data Volume (Bytes)";"Device Manufacturer";"Device Model";"Product Description";"Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06";"427";"060";"137765";"Samsung Korea";"Samsung SM-G900I";"$39 Plan";"0.131383"
"2015-10-06";"592";"620";"0";"Apple Inc";"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)";"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16";"0"
"2015-10-06";"007";"290";"0";"Apple Inc";"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)";"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -";"0"
"2015-10-06";"592";"050";"48836832";"Apple Inc";"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)";"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan";"46.5744"
"2016-04-27";"498";"220";"146610";"Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd";"OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006";"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)";"0.139818"
"2015-10-06";"409";"720";"113755347";"Samsung Korea";"Samsung SM-G360G";"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN";"108.486"
"2015-10-06";"742";"620";"19840943";"Apple Inc";"Apple iPhone S (A1530)";"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2";"18.9218"
"2015-10-06";"387";"180";"0";"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd";"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11";"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4";"0"
```

change the delimiter from , to | and add the new column at the end

```
$ sed 's/","/"|"/g' < test2 | awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$8=q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $8= q n/(1024*1024)q}1'
"Rec Open Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data Volume (Bytes)"|"Device Manufacturer"|"Device Model"|"Product Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06"|"427"|"060"|"137765"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900I"|"$39 Plan"|"0.131383"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"620"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"007"|"290"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"050"|"48836832"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)"|"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"|"46.5744"
"2016-04-27"|"498"|"220"|"146610"|"Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd"|"OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006"|"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"|"0.139818"
"2015-10-06"|"409"|"720"|"113755347"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G360G"|"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"|"108.486"
"2015-10-06"|"742"|"620"|"19840943"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone S (A1530)"|"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"|"18.9218"
"2015-10-06"|"387"|"180"|"0"|"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd"|"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11"|"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"|"0"
```

change the delimiter from , to ; and to insert it before the second last column

```
$ sed 's/","/";"/g' < test2 | awk -F';' -v OFS=';' -v q='"' 'NR==1{$(NF-1)=q"Data_Volume_MB"q FS $(NF-1)} NR>1{n=$4; gsub(/"/,"",n); $(NF-1)= q n/(1024*1024)q FS $(NF-1)}1'
"Rec Open Date";"MSISDN";"IMEI";"Data Volume (Bytes)";"Device Manufacturer";"Data_Volume_MB";"Device Model";"Product Description"
"2015-10-06";"427";"060";"137765";"Samsung Korea";"0.131383";"Samsung SM-G900I";"$39 Plan"
"2015-10-06";"592";"620";"0";"Apple Inc";"0";"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)";"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"
"2015-10-06";"007";"290";"0";"Apple Inc";"0";"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)";"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"2015-10-06";"592";"050";"48836832";"Apple Inc";"46.5744";"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)";"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"
"2016-04-27";"498";"220";"146610";"Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd";"0.139818";"OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006";"$29.95 Carryover Plan (1GB)"
"2015-10-06";"409";"720";"113755347";"Samsung Korea";"108.486";"Samsung SM-G360G";"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"
"2015-10-06";"742";"620";"19840943";"Apple Inc";"18.9218";"Apple iPhone S (A1530)";"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
"2015-10-06";"387";"180";"0";"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd";"0";"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11";"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"
```

Comment: The best way would be to use a tool that supports CSV more or less natively.  Python has a CSV module as standard; Perl has one as an extension that's installable from CPAN (`Text::CSV`, `Text::CSV_XS`, `Text::CSV_PP` — they're closely related).  There's also an open source C++ program `csvfix` that can be very useful.

Comment: You could also take a look at [How can I read a CSV file if only non-empty fields are wrapped by double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507866/how-can-i-read-a-csv-file-if-only-non-empty-fields-are-wrapped-by-double-quotes/35509045#35509045).  If you have GNU Awk, there are some powerful techniques in use there to handle both commas within double quotes and adjacent commas indicating empty fields.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler is GNU Awk gawk?would an idea be to just awk on columns other than the column with commas in the double quotes i.e. insert it after column 3?

Comment: GNU Awk is sometimes installed as `gawk` as well as, or instead of, `awk`.  And the `FPAT` technique requires GNU Awk 4.x — 3.x doesn't support it.

Comment: If your data has commas in the field values, then you really need a command sensitive enough to parse the fields correctly.  You might be able to take a short cut by instead of adding `$8`, adding `$(NF+1)`; this at least guarantees that the new data will be at the end of the line, regardless of the other fields.  If the column you're analyzing is `$4` and it isn't preceded by any comma-containing field values, then this could sidestep the issue for you.  However, if `$4` were after a comma-containing field value, you'd be stuck again; laziness is great until it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your field separator first, like so (here I am changing it from `,` to `|`):

```
sed 's/","/"|"/g' < test2 > newfile
```

Then use your `awk` code on `newfile`.

You could put this all in one line of course (I'm not using your `awk` code here but just my own `awk` code as an example):

```
sed 's/","/"|"/g' < test2 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print  $1}'
```

In response to OP comments, be sure to run your command as such (notice I changed the `-F,` to `-F"|"`:

```
    sed 's/","/"|"/g' < test2 | awk -F"|" -v OFS=, -v q='"' 'NR==1{$8=q"Data_Volume_MB"q} NR>1{$8=$4; gsub(/"/,"",$8); $8= q $8/(1024*1024)q}1'
```

Using your data, here is my results:

```
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description","Data_Volume_MB"
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan","0.131383"
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16","0"
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -","0"
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan","46.5744"
"2016-04-27","498","220","146610","Guangdong Oppo Mobile Telecommunications Corp Ltd","OPPO X9076,OPPO R6006,OPPO R6001,OPPO N5116,OPPO X9006","$ Carryover Plan (1GB)","0.139818"
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN","108.486"
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2","18.9218"
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4","0"
```

Comment: It is, mercifully, fairly improbable, but this single CSV field would suffer at the hands of your `sed` script:  `"abc"",""def"`.  When extracted, the field contains `abc","def`.  Your `sed` script would map that comma to a pipe.

Comment: tks got there in the end